# Sending Html as parameter in translate decorator in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, parameters, translation, decorator

When I try to send html as parameter in translate decorator my html code is displayed as text and not as html. Like in code under:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js/v1.0.2/messageformat.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.15.2/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/2.15.2/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie/2.15.2/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-local/2.15.2/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-url/2.15.2/angular-translate-loader-url.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files/2.15.2/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-handler-log/2.15.2/angular-translate-handler-log.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <p>{{ 'HEADLINE' | translate }}</p>
  <p>{{ 'PARAGRAPH' | translate }}</p>
</div>


  </body>
```

```
var translations = {
  HEADLINE: 'What an awesome module!',
  PARAGRAPH: 'This is cool link <a href="http://google.com">test</a> Check it out!'
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // add translation table
  $translateProvider.translations('en', translations);
   $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
 }]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

As a result I get:

```
This is cool link <a href="http://google.com">test</a> Check it out!
```

html code it self in browser instead of anchor html representation.
I want anchor to be processed as html tag.

Anybody has a suggestion?

Comment: replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to actually process the HTML instead of outputting it as characters, you can use the [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive. In your case, it will look like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="'PARAGRAPH' | translate"></p>
```

Comment: ng-bind-html directive solved my problem! Thank you.

Comment: @Michael2000 No problem. Don't forget to accept my answer.